# Workaround for Visibilty.Hidden state- Windows Phone 8.1 App Development

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I cannot assign the Visibility State to Hidden for a ProgressBar. I've read that  in the WPF model, Hidden denotes a visibility state where the object should not render, but should still occupy space in a WPF layout. Silverlight does not support Hidden. Is there a workaround to get the same effect as Hidden in my app?

Comment: Change the Opacity to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visibility.Hidden is WPF only. Both Silverlight and Windows.UI.Xaml use only Visibility.Visible or Collapsed.

You can set the UIElement's [Opacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.uielement.opacity(v=vs.105).aspx) property to zero to prevent it from rendering. This value is also readily animatiable so you can fade the element in and out smoothly.