# Setting the position of controls inside a stackpanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `ListBox` that has multiple `ListBoxItem`, I have used a `StackPanel` inside my `ListBoxItem` that has an `Image` & a `TextBlock` control. I am programmatically setting the Visibility of the `Image` based on the selection of the `TextBlock`.

I am facing an issue where in when the image is `Collapsed`, the TextBlock is moving towards the left, this is not what is expected.

```
<ListBoxItem Tag="ATCListBox">

    <StackPanel x:Name="ATCPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Image
            x:Name="atcTick"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Height="45" Width="45"
            Source="ms-appx:///Assets/greentick.png"
        />

        <TextBlock
            Text="ATC"
            Foreground="#0078D7"
            Margin="45,0,0,0"
            FontSize="32"
            FontFamily="{ThemeResource Bold}"
            FontWeight="Normal"
            SelectionHighlightColor="Blue"
        />

    </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged your question with WPF, but in a comment-reply you said you're using UWP.

In UWP the WPF `Visibility="Hidden"` option is removed and instead `Opacity="0"` can be used to hide an element while still ensuring its space is occupied.

See here: [Workaround for Visibilty.Hidden state- Windows Phone 8.1 App Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097153/workaround-for-visibilty-hidden-state-windows-phone-8-1-app-development)

```
<Image
    x:Name="atcTick"
    Opacity="0"
    Height="45" Width="45"
    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/greentick.png"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Visiblity="Collapsed"` means the `<Image />` element won't take up any space - it's equivalent to CSS' `display: none;` - if you want the space to remain occupied you should use `Visibility="Hidden"` which is equivalent to CSS' `opacity: 0` or `visiblity: hidden`.

Comment: hidden is not there in UWP XAML

Comment: @Apoorv you tagged your question with WPF, not UWP.

Answer (score 0):

It is the espected behaviour. You should set Visibility as hidden if you want to reserve the space.

> Visible: Display the element.
>   Hidden: Do not display the element, but reserve space for the element in layout.
>   Collapsed: Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout.

.